# Magento Sorting some categories given by id

Tags: php, magento, sorting, tree, categories

I would like to sort some categories as set in the category tree.

 The question then is, if I’ve:

 category1 with: parent1, path1, position1, level1

 category2 with: parent2, path2, position2, level2

 category3 with: parent3, path3, position3, level3

 How to programmatically sort these cats based on the category tree ? 

Sorting by position is not enough if these categories lies in different levels and/branches

Comment: Give an example the result and input categories

Comment: As in main post (i.e.: 0 is root): <br> 
cat1: parent1 = 0, path then is 0/1, pos1: 1, level1: 1<br>
cat2: parent2 = 1, path then is 0/1/2, pos2:1, level2:2<br>
cat3: parent3 = 0, path then is 0/3, pos3:2, level3:1<br>
cat4: parent4 = 2, path then is 0/2/4, pos:2, level4:2<br>
The result sorting should be:
cat1
cat2
cat4
cat3<br>
that because cat4 is under cat2 that comes before cat3

Answer (score 0):

there are bewlow code for magento category filter.

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
    ->addAttributeToSort('parent_id',$parentcata_id);
->addAttributeToSort('parent_id',$parentcata_id);
->addAttributeToSort('position_id',$pos_of_cat);
->addAttributeToSort('level',$level_of_cat);
```

if hope it will be working.

Comment: I don't have the complete collection but just some category and would like to know if cat1 comes before or after cat2, even if these are on different level or branches of the tree

Comment: Could you explain how it works by a real query on the magecatalog_category_entity table please ? Is it possible to sort some categories just by one query ?